# nautilus won't accept password in command

Tags: nautilus

Hi I'm trying to connect to ftp using nautilus. But it doesn't accept the password.
An example how I tried to connect:

`nautilus ftp://username:PASSWORD@example.com`

sftp also doesn't work. It treats the username and password as username. In the example is asks for a password for user `username:PASSWORD`

Am I doing something wrong? I found the syntax [here](http://www.lessons4you.info/how-to-connect-ssh-sftp-and-ftp-servers-using-nautilus-ubuntu-13-04/)

Comment: Isn't there the possiblity your user credentials are simply invalid?

Comment: No using `nautilus ftp://username@example.com` then entering the password works. The password is just letters and numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just store the password on the keyring. Then you won't be asked for a password again.

When prompted the first time, choose to store the password. You can't input the password to Nautilus from the command line.

A working alternative is `gvfs-mount`, which asks for the password on the terminal if not stored, instead of using a window.

```
gvfs-mount ftp://user@server && nautilus ftp://user@server
```

As the password is being read from the standard input, you can pass it from the command line like this:

```
gvfs-mount ftp://user@server <<< "passwordHere"
nautilus ftp://user@server
```

Please notice this is very insecure, since the password will be stored on your bash history file. I recommend disabling history before doing this, then reenable it.

```
HISTIGNORE="*"
gvfs-mount ftp://user@server <<< "passwordHere"
nautilus ftp://user@server &
unset HISTIGNORE
```

You can also finetune the `HISTIGNORE` expression, so it doesn't match any command starting with `gvfs-mount` and still keep other commands.

```
HISTIGNORE="gvfs-mount *"
gvfs-mount ftp://user@server <<< "passwordHere"
nautilus ftp://user@server &
```

You can write this a a one-liner also by using semicolons:

```
HISTIGNORE="gvfs-mount *"; gvfs-mount ftp://user@server <<< "passwordHere" ; nautilus ftp://user@server &
```

You can also avoid writing the URL twice by storing it on a variable:

```
CONNECT_TO="ftp://user@server" ; HISTIGNORE="gvfs-mount *"; gvfs-mount $CONNECT_TO <<< "passwordHere" ; nautilus $CONNECT_TO &
```

Comment: Very nice and complete answer. Tnx

Answer (score 0):

You have to use it like this:

```
ftp://example.com/
```

Then Nautilus will prompt for a username and password.

You could also use ssh to connect:

```
ssh ftp://username@example.com/
```

Comment: I know, But I don't want that. I want to connect with 1 command nothing more. no prompts

Comment: Why? If your current try doesn't work you should look at alternatives like the one I proposed.

Comment: I want to be able to login with one click(command) not copying the password. Which is an extra step. I'm asking for 1 step solution. So I can view files in the GUI/finder/explorer/(what ubuntu calls it)

Comment: this won't work for me on some hosts as they require to provide a password in the connection parameters. eg: godaddy's hosting